# NSTimer iPhone resume from current time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is my code for an iPhone stopwatch app, when you hit the start button it will count up in the right format and all works fine, as well as the stop button and reset.  The problem is every time i hit stop and then start again it creates a new timer and does not continue from the last one.  How can i create a pause and be able to continue from the current time?

Thanks

```
NSDate *startDate;
NSTimer *stopWatchTimer;


-(void)showActivity {

    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];
    NSDate *timerDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SS"];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0.0]];
    NSString *timeString=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:timerDate];
    stopWatchLabel.text = timeString;
    [dateFormatter release];
}

- (IBAction)onStartPressed:(id)sender {
    startDate = [[NSDate date]retain];
    stopWatchTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1/10 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)onStopPressed:(id)sender {
    [stopWatchTimer invalidate];
    stopWatchTimer = nil;
    [self showActivity];
}

- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender; {
    stopWatchLabel.text = @"00:00.00";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't set the startDate on every start press.  Just the very first, and after any reset.  A boolean state variable can help keep track.

Answer (score 1):

During Pause, you probably want to keep timeInterval so far into a iVar

accumulatedInterval = [currentDate timeIntervalSinceDate:startDate];

and add to the timeInterval all the time.